# symfony2 doctrine:generate:CRUD error

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony2 framework. I have a mysql db that I have prior to installing symfony. So I was able to generate schema based on the db.

I am trying to generate the CRUD controller for one of the tables. This is a user table and the primary key is UserId. However, when I run doctrine:generate:CRUD, I get the following error

The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named "id" with a getId() method.

Do I have to have Id as the PK identifier? is that the best practice? All my PKs for the tables are defined by tablenameid.

I have the get method for the User entity class as getUserid().
How can I let the CRUD generator know that?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you add a `getId()` method that just does `return getUserid();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has to be 'id' as PK identifier. I think there might be some error in your entity.

```
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
private $userid;
```

YML File:

```
Bundle\BundleBundle\Entity\Example:
  type: entity
  table: Example
  fields:
    userid:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

Comment: This is the entry I have in User.php entity


/**
     * @var integer $userid
     */
    private $userid;

Comment: and my User.orm.yml is like this 

 type: entity
  table: user
  fields:
    userid:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: USERID
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY

Comment: Code added in my answer.

This is working for me, regenerate your entities and then drop the database and create it new. Should work?

Comment: Just read your question again and saw that your want to use the CRUD generator. It doesnt seem to be possible with another identifier than "id"

Comment: Ah! so how did you generate your controller. I read somewhere only generate:crud is available now.